# pull back of a Kähler form by a smooth circle group action on a compact Kähler manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose a compact Kähler manifold $(M,\omega)$ admits a smooth circle action $g_t,~t\in S^1$. So the pull back of the Kähler form $g_t^{\ast}(\omega)$ is a nondegenerate two-form. Since the circle action is only smooth and may not preserve the complex structure, $g_t^{\ast}(\omega)$ may not be $(1,1)$-from. My question is if it is possible for some special manifolds or under some special cases $g_t^{\ast}(\omega)$ is $(1,1)$ for any $t$.

Comment: Certainly it's possible and happens all the time when the circle action does preserve the complex structure and the metric (which is what one normally means when one says that a Kähler manifold (as opposed to just the underlying manifold) admits a circle action.  Do you mean to assume that the circle action does *not* preserve the complex structure but *does* preserve $\omega$?

Comment: @RobertBryant Here I only assume that this circle action is a smooth action and may neither preserve the complex structure nor the Kahler form $\omega$. If it preserves $\omega$, then the circle action is Killing and its generating vector field is real holomorphic and thus necessarily preserves the complex structure. (Am I right??)

Comment: Are you assuming that the circle action preserves the underlying metric of the Kähler structure?  (In that case, it is Killing by definition, whether it preserves $\omega$ or not.)  Or are you starting out assuming that the circle action is completely unrelated to any of the metric, the complex structure, or the $2$-form, and you just want to know whether it is possible that $g_t(\omega)$ remains always of type (1,1) with respect to the initial holomorphic structure?

Comment: @RobertBryant Your last sentence is exactly what I want to know. I only assume that the cirlce action $\subset\text{Diff}^+(M)$ and is completely unrelated to any of the metric, complex structure or the Kahler form and I want to know if it is possible $g_t^{\ast}(\omega)$ remains always of type $(1,1)$ with respect to the original holomorphic structure.

Comment: Take $\phi\in \mathrm{Diff}^+(S^2)$, and consider the pullbacks $\phi^*J$ and $\phi^*\omega$ of the standard complex structure $J$ and Kaehler form $\omega$. Let $S^1$ act by rotation around the $z$-axis. The action will usually not preserve $\phi^*J$, but $g_t^*(\phi^*\omega)$ is trivially a $(1,1)$-form.

Comment: @TimPerutz  Why do you choose a $\phi$? I just want to know if $g_t^{\ast}(\omega)$ is still a (1,1) form with respect to the original J. In your example the answer is affirmative. What I want to know is whether it is a generic phenomenon.

Comment: @Kevin:  Another way to say it is that Tim is using $\phi$ to construct a circle action on the $2$-sphere that does not preserve the standard complex structure $J$.  (He conjugates the rotation about the $z$-axis, which *does* preserve the standard complex structure, with $\phi$ to make a new circle action that does not preserve $J$.)  Then his point is that this circle action doesn't preserve $J$ but does preserve its $(1,1)$-forms, since there isn't any other kind of $2$-form on the $2$-sphere.

Comment: @RobertBryant Thanks and I understand the meaning of the comments from Tim. However, I am still eagerly concerned with my originial question. Because I can neither find a counterexample such that $g_t^{\ast}(ω)$ is not a (1,1)-form for some t nor prove it affirmatively.

Comment: The pull-back of a closed $(1, 1)$-current by a holomorphic map $\pi$ is
always well-defined, when we take a local plurisubharmonic potential $ϕ $ such
that $T = i∂\bar ∂ϕ$ and write $\pi ^*T = i∂\bar ∂(ϕ◦\pi)$

Comment: Take a holomorphic map $\pi:X\to Y$ such that  the leaves of the foliation coincide with the fiber of $\pi$, then the pull back of
any Kahler metric on $Y$ to $X$ gives rise to a homogeneous holomorphic
Monge-Ampère foliation and the degenerate Kahler form
can be the pull back of a Kahler metric on $Y$. See Proposition 6.4. https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214425215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I fully understand your question, which (apparently) is whether *every* circle action on a compact Kähler manifold $(M,J,\omega)$ must preserve the $J$-type of $\omega$, I can answer it.  The answer is 'no'.

Consider the $4$-dimensional case.  Observe that a circle action that preserves *all* of the $(1,1)$-forms must be holomorphic since, for a circle action, preserving all of the $(1,1)$-forms is equivalent to preserving all of the $(2,0)$-forms, and doing the latter is exactly equivalent to preserving $J$.

Now, start with a circle action $g_t$ on $(M^4,J,\omega)$ that has an isolated fixed point $p$.  (For example, choose one of the standard ones on $\mathbb{CP}^2$.)  Let $X$ be the vector field that generates $g_t$, so that $X(p)=0$, and $X$ induces a nontrivial circle action on $T_pM$.  If this circle action does preserve $J_p$, then conjugate $g_t$ by a nonholomorphic diffeomorphism that fixes $p$ to get a new circle action such that the flow of its $X$ does not preserve $J$ at $p$.  Then the flow of this $X$ will not preserve all of the $(1,1)$-forms at $p$.  If this $X$ does not preserve the $J$-type of $\omega_p$, then we are done.  Otherwise, let $\alpha$ be a $(1,1)$-form at $p$ such that the flow of $X$ does not keep $\alpha$ of $J$-type $(1,1)$.  Choose any closed $(1,1)$-form $\eta$ on $M$ such that $\eta_p = \alpha$.  Then, for some small $\epsilon\not=0$, the form $\omega{+}\epsilon\eta$ will be a positive $(1,1)$-form on $(M,J)$.  Then $(M, J, \omega{+}\epsilon\eta)$ is a Kähler manifold, but the circle action generated by $X$ will not keep $\omega{+}\epsilon\eta$ of $J$-type $(1,1)$ because this doesn't hold at $p$.